# How to access REMOTE_ADDR in a model's save() method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model (UserProfile) with which I want to record a user's IP address when new user accounts are created.

I've begin the process of overriding the Django model's save() method, but I am totally uncertain how to properly access HttpRequest attributes from within a model. Can any of you guys help? Google was unable to provide a specific answer for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need to pass on request information from the view to your save-method.
Consider that saving an instance doesn't always have to be invoked from a http request (for a simple example think of calling `save` in the python shell).

If you need to access the `request` object within the admin while saving, you can override it's `save_model` method:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    # do something with obj and request here....
    obj.save()
```

But otherwise you always have to pass it on from the view:

```
def my_view(request):
    obj = MyClass(ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

Or to make this easier to re-use, make a method on the model like:

```
def foo(self, request):
    self.ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    self..... = request.....
```

and call it from your view with `obj.foo(request)`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will put it in the registration view, then. It won't work to put it in an admin save_model() method, because if I recorded the REMOTE_ADDR value while one of our site administrators was creating a user account through the admin, it would record her IP address, instead of the user's.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the request from [within the admin](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/), but you can't do it in general code. If you need it then you'll have to assign it manually in the view.

Comment: Really? There's no way to declare self.ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] from within the model's save() method?

Comment: There is no way to get to the request from anywhere other than where it is explicitly sent.

Comment: @tommytwoeyes Nope, models are honestly agnostic even to HTTP itself, so the concept of a "request" doesn't mean anything to them.  Separation of concerns!

Comment: Ok well, that is understandable. However, if I'm only able to set the ip_address attribute of the UserProfile from within a view, doesn't that tend to couple the view and the model too tightly? And if I need to modify the UserProfile's ip_address from somewhere else, and I repeat my code for that, isn't that somewhat un-pythonic?

Not trying to sound argumentative - I'm just really new to Python and Django and am trying to understand the best way to accomplish this. Thanks!

Comment: If *you* want to couple them together and violate DRY then that is your prerogative. But don't ask Django to do either.

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams : But, I don't want to couple them together or violate DRY principles. I want to avoid that.

So, I am asking how to accomplish setting the user's IP address value to a model attribute in keeping with the loosely coupled, DRY principles. How can I best do that?

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams Thank you. I understand what not to do. How would you recommend solving this problem?